# How to get event click Ok dialog

Tags: java, swing

I have showdialog

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Eggs are not supposed to be green.");
```

[image]

How to get event when I click the Ok button?

Comment: Please post your code you have written so far so people can help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code will be blocked until you click

```
    System.out.println("before click");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Eggs are not supposed to be green.");
    System.out.println("after click - do your code here");
```